# How to use a strong type system to model business constraints?

Tags: design, haskell

Following up on my [ambiguous question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/305478/using-a-strong-type-system-in-the-real-world-say-for-large-scale-web-apps), here's a question that is probably more focused.

Consider the following code snippet form a Haskell program:

```
data NightWatchCommand = InvalidCommand | DownloadCommand { url :: String } | PauseCommand { gid :: String } | UnpauseCommand { gid :: String } | StatusCommand { gid :: String } deriving (Show, Eq)
data AuthNightwatchCommand = AuthNightwatchCommand {
  command :: NightWatchCommand,
  user :: User
}
```

Now, the business constraint I want to enforce via the type-system is this: it should **not** be possible to instantiate an unauthenticated `NightwatchCommand`. And the only way to instantiate an `AuthNightwatchCommand` should be via a special function, say:

```
fromIncomingMsg :: String -> AuthNightwatchCommand
```

Just to provide greater context, the string argument to this function could possibly be:

```
status <some-id> <auth-token>
```

Now, to complicate matters further, `fromIncomingMsg` needs to validate the `<auth-token>` from the DB. Which means, it will do IO. A more appropriate function signature would be:

```
fromIncomingMsg :: String -> IO (AuthNightwatchCommand)
```

Apart from shoving this into a module and hiding the data constructors, is there any other way to do this?

Comment: @PyRulez is there no other way? This seems like hiding the key under the doormat. Doesn't feel like using a strong type system to your advantage. More like using conventions. What if I have 30 such constraints in my system? 30 modules?

Comment: Hmm, how 'bout typeclasses? (Make AuthNightwatchCommand an instance of a typeclass `Authorized`, which has a method `String -> IO a`. Now, functions should only deal with things of type `(forall a. Authorized a => a)`. Even if something makes a fraudulent `Authorized`, nothing can make a fraudulent `(forall a. Authorized a => a)`.)

Comment: What's wrong with putting it into a module and hiding the data constructors? AFAIK, that is the simplest way to do this sort of thing in Haskell. If, as you say, you plan to have a very complex system with a lot of this going on, then you might e.g. have a type class `Authenticable` that allows instances to harness common code while still hiding their data constructors (and the details of their individual logic) in modules. Having a lot of modules is not necessarily a bad thing; a lot of large Haskell projects seem to have many. I think modules are intended to be used for encapsulation.

Answer (score 4):

> Now, the business constraint I want to enforce via the type-system is this: it should **not** be possible to instantiate an unauthenticated `NightwatchCommand`.

Now, maybe I'm missing some piece of context here, but this has me very puzzled for the following reason: why would a "business constraint" care about what `NightWatchCommand`s get instantiated or not?  It sounds to me like the constraint should be something more like this:

- It should be impossible for an unauthenticated user to execute a night watch command.

And to my mind this suggests an organization like the following:

```
module NightWatch (NightWatchCommand, execute) where

import Something.Auth

data NightWatchCommand = ...
data Result = ...

execute 
  :: Auth 
  -> NightWatchCommand 
  -> IO (Either InsufficientPermissions Result)
execute auth cmd = do 
  allowed <- checkAuth auth cmd
  if allowed
  then fmap Right (reallyExecute cmd)
  else Left (InsufficientPermissions $ "insufficient auth: " ++ (cmd, auth))

reallyExecute :: NightWatchCommand -> IO Result
reallyExecute cmd = ...
```

Basically, what I'm arguing here is that security is not part of the `NightWatchCommand`'s set of concerns—the core concerns for that type are just what the commands are.  Security is a concern for the *interpreter* that executes the commands.  If the only interpreter you provide demands and checks authentication, and you disallow other modules from writing their own interpreters (by not exporting the constructors for the `NightWatchCommand` type), then all callers have to go through your interpreter.

Comment: I agree with you, but partially. You're right in saying that authentication is different from interpreting a command. However, what if every function that were dealing with a `NightwatchCommand` also needed to know something about who issued that command. Example: logCommand :: Auth -> NightwatchCommand -> IO (). Or meterUsage :: Auth -> NightwatchCommand -> IO (). If, (almost) every time a NightwatchCommand were being used also needed the relevant Auth, it would be better to "tie" them together into one type. Hence, my question.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this (testing this code is an exercise for the reader):

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types, GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

class Authorized a where
    fromIncomingMsg :: String -> IO (AuthNightwatchCommand)

instance Authroized AuthNightwatchCommand where
    fromIncomeMsg = error "Todo"

newtype Auth = Auth {unAuth :: forall a. Authorized a => a deriving (Authorized)}

--Please only use Auth
```

`unAuth` can convert from `Auth` to `AuthNightwatchCommand` (and is safe for others to use).

Answer (score 0):

The question does not really give enough information, but judging from the comments phantom types might be (part of) a solution:

```
data NightwatchCommand' auth = NightwatchCommand' NightWatchCommand

data IsAuthorised
data NotAuthorised

fromIncomingMsg :: String -> IO (NightwatchCommand' NotAuthorised)

withNightwatchCommand :: ?? -> NightwatchCommand' a
                            -> NightwatchCommand' a

withNightwatchCommandUnsafe :: ?? -> NightwatchCommand' a
                                  -> NightwatchCommand' NotAuthorised

authoriseNightwatch :: Auth -> NightwatchCommand' a
                            -> NightwatchCommand' IsAuthorised

protectedFunction :: NightwatchCommand' IsAuthorised -> StartMissilesFunction
```